# Bootstrap navbar alighn menu items on main

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

I am looking for a way where I can align the menu items in the middle of the navbar.

I increased the width of the navbar but would like to move the links to the middle 
of the navbar.

Any help or examples will be apreciated.

Here is my current navbar layout.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="index.php" title="logo">
          <img src="images/logo.png">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="why">item1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="scroll-link" data-id="products">item2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">item3</a>
          </li>             
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
        </ul>      
      </nav>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And here is my CSS

```
.navbar { min-width: 100%; font-size: 20px; background-color: #3A424C; border-bottom-width: 0px;}

.navbar-nav>li>a { 
    padding-top: 70px; 
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
    line-height: 25px; 
}

.nav.navbar-nav>li>a{
    color: white;
}

.nav.navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.nav.navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(110, 206, 230, 1);
}

.navbar-brand { padding: 1px 10px; } 

.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

/* Flip around the padding for proper display in narrow viewports */
.navbar-wrapper > .container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.navbar-wrapper .navbar .container {
  width: auto;
}

.navbar img{ 
    width: 185px; 
}
```

You can see a edited sample here

https://jsfiddle.net/v49w742k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping if there's a jsfiddle link so I can assist you in a sure way.

Anyway, try this css code for the .navbar-nav class:

```
.navbar-nav{
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
float: none;
}
```

Comment: It was close but now the menu items are pulling to the right and the the navbar padding becomes destorted

Comment: I didn't see where the problem is when i look on the jsfiddle link, the items are centered and when you minimize the screen width, they were centered too, as well as the navbar-right item.The only thing is that there's a scroll visible vertically, so i added a property to make the menu show off completely in small screen devices: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/v49w742k/2/)